# Can I see returned HTML responses rendered in Safari dev tools?

Tags: html, safari, frontend, htmx

In some browser developer tools network tabs you can see a requests response rendered if it is HTML. In other words, if the HTML for a small table is returned you can actually see the response as either the markup or an actual rendered table right there within dev tools. Does Safari have this?